# I just can't start Laravel on Apache2/Ubuntu. Give me some suggestions

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Am trying to get to the laravel welcome screen while running Apache on Ubuntu.

Here are the steps I take:

1) I download composer.phar file

2) I create new laravel project with:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

Now I have laravel project in my var/www/html folder.

3) Now I create a virtual host file called myapp.conf in apache2/sites-available folder.

Content of that file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 # Host that will serve this project.
    ServerName      app.dev

    # The location of our projects public directory.
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/nino-laravel-project/public


        # Rewrites for pretty URLs, better not to rely on .htaccess.
        <Directory /var/www/html/nino-laravel-project/public>
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                Options -MultiViews
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
            </IfModule>
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Now when I type app.dev in my browser all I get is Apache's welcome screen.

Note that I have installed all other requirements like PHP5, crypt etc..

What am I missing here?

Comment: what version of apache?

Comment: apache version is 2.4.16